# The complement of a bounded region (the exterior region) is also a bounded region?

Tags: general-topology

My textbook, *An Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of the Navier-Stokes Equations* by Galdi, says that $\Omega$ is a type of region where flow occurs. To this end, it distinguishes between the following cases:

> (i) $\Omega$ is bounded;
>
> (ii) $\Omega$ is the complement of a bounded region (in short: $\Omega$ is an *exterior* region).
>
> In both circumstances $\Omega$ has a bounded boundary.

So the complement of a bounded region (the exterior region) is also a bounded region? Can someone please explain why this is the case?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn’t that an “or” in between?

Comment: @Randall Between (i) and (ii)? I see no "or" in the textbook (p. 4).

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a bounded region in $\mathbb{R}^n$, say, then its complement is *never* bounded.

Comment: @ThePointer  but it says these are different cases.   That means different unrelated scenarios (or).

Comment: @Randall Yes, that's my point exactly. So it seems to me that it is saying that *both*  cases are bounded, which means that it is saying that the complement of a bounded region is also bounded? That's my confusion: Is the complement of a bounded region bounded? If so, why?

Comment: That’s not what cases means in mathematics.

Comment: @uniquesolution Huh... So did the author make an error here in saying that the case (ii) is also bounded?

Comment: @Randall But, since it says "*In both circumstances $\Omega$ is bounded*" I don't see how it could be interpreted differently? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: The community wiki answer below is perfect.

Comment: No.  It says it has bounded BOUNDARY.  That doesn’t mean $\Omega$ is bounded.

Comment: @Randall Oh hahaha. Ok, I see the subtle difference: There's a difference between a *bounded region* and a *bounded boundary*. So a *bounded region* does **not** necessarily have a *bounded boundary*?

Comment: Have you read the answer below?  It answers your question.

Comment: @Randall see my comment underneath it. It seems that I missed the distinction between *bounded region* and *bounded boundary*?

Comment: This answers my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849142/what-is-the-difference-between-bounded-boundary-and-a-bounded-domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "or" in the text - the author expects you to provide it when he says "cases". He wants to consider regions with a bounded boundary. Bounded regions have that property. So do the complements of bounded regions.

**Edit** in response to a comment.

The author could have written two sentences instead of the fragment you quoted:

> If $\Omega$ is bounded then $\Omega$  has a bounded boundary.
>
> If the complement of $\Omega$ is bounded then $\Omega$  has a bounded
>   boundary.

Then you would be less confused, but others might find the phrasing clunky.

I think you are overthinking this. Read on in the text and come back to the question only if you need to. I doubt that will happen.

Comment: But I *was* thinking of it as an "or" situation: The two cases are (i) $\Omega$ is bounded; **or** (ii) $\Omega$ is the complement of a bounded region. But in the case of (ii), we have that $\Omega$ is the complement of a bounded region; and the text immediately proceeding it claims that it is a circumstance where $\Omega$ has a bounded boundary. Does that mean that the complement of a bounded region $\Omega$ in (ii) is also bounded, or is there a distinction that I'm missing between *bounded region* and *bounded boundary*? Sorry for if i'm misunderstanding your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb R^2$, consider
$$\Omega = \{\,(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1\,\}.$$
This, an **open unit disk**, is clearly a bounded region (all points have distance less tna $1$ from th eorigin).
Its complement
$$\Omega':=\Bbb R^2\setminus \Omega= \{\,(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\ge 1\,\}$$
is **the plane with a hole**, and certainly not bounded, e.g., because it contains the points $(x,0)$ with $x$ arbitrarily large. (In contrast to $\Omega$, $\Omega'$ is also closed).

Finally, the boundary of $\Omega$,
$$\partial \Omega = \{\,(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2= 1\,\},$$
is the **unit circle** and is bounded. The boundary of $\Omega'$ is the same unit circle, hence still bounded.
So $\Omega$ is bounded (and therefore has bounded boundary), whereas $\Omega'$ is not bounded, but happens to have bounded boundary. (Of course, there also exist regions such that the region itself as well as its complement is unboudned, e.g., the half plane  $\Omega'':=\{\,(x,y)\mid x>0\,\}$; in that case, the boundary (of either) is also unbounded).